# How do I show the Auth0 login page when using FeathersJS

Tags: javascript, authentication, auth0, feathersjs

I'm using FeathersJS as a REST service but I need the user to be able to login with Auth0. How do I show the Auth0 login page to the user?

Answer (score 0):

After checking FeathersJS website, I saw you can run it paired with express. So it should be alright to use Auth0's express quickstart to build that connection. I have referenced said doc below should help you on your path. Thanks!

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/nodejs/01-authorization